# azure storage copy: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format

Tags: azure, go, azure-storage

I'm using [this library](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage#Blob.Copy).

When I run:

```
b := container.GetBlobReference("bar")
err := b.Copy("foo", nil)
```

I get:

> storage: service returned error: StatusCode=400,
>   ErrorCode=InvalidHeaderValue, ErrorMessage=The value for one of the
>   HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
>   RequestId:66d0164b-001e-0028-2c4f-78a847000000
>   Time:2017-12-18T22:26:59.9585462Z, RequestInitiated=Mon, 18 Dec 2017
>   22:26:59 GMT, RequestId=66d0164b-001e-0028-2c4f-78a847000000, API
>   Version=2016-05-31, QueryParameterName=, QueryParameterValue=

File "foo" **does** exist.

Perhaps the hint is in `QueryParameterName` and `QueryParameterValue` having no values.

Comment: As written, this question is rather unclear. Great that you linked to the library you're using but... you haven't shown all your code. For instance: how you set up the storage client (e.g. how did you initialize `container`?). We don't know if it's something you did wrong, an issue with the library you're using, or something else. Please edit your question to be more specific. (**Note: When editing, do not include your real connection string; just show your code**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source to Copy must be absolute:

```
destBlob := h.client.GetBlobReference(to)
sourceBlob := h.client.GetBlobReference(from)
err := destBlob.Copy(sourceBlob.GetURL(), nil)
```